# How find role name and id of a specific user id who is not logged in using Sentinel in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

How to find role name and id of a specific user id who is not logged in using Sentinel in Laravel?

```
// **** I have used this code =>
<?php Sentinel::getUser(4)->inRole('admin'); ?>
```

But this doesn't work as Sentinel::getUser() works only for logged in user.
  But I need to find role name and role id of nonlogged user in one of my    managament , so what should be the script. I need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have got a solution to my problem , and its working in the view page   , the code that i have used is given below

```
<?php
    $user_id=3;
    $userR = App\User::find($user_id);
    $chk=$userR->inRole('admin');
    if($chk)
    {
        //***** logic comes here ******
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get any user based on their id by calling `$user = User::find(4)`. Then with sentinel you should be able to call `$roles = $user->roles` which will return all the roles that are assigned to that user or call `$user->inRole('admin')` to check if they're in a specific role.

EDIT

For this to work you will need to have a User model class set up in the app directory that extends the base Sentinel EloquentUser class. The top of the file should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Sentinel;

class User extends EloquentUser {
```

Comment: when I'm using the script $user = User::find(4); in my view getting this error => Class 'User' not found @Harry loyd

Comment: Do you have a User model set up that extends the Sentinel Eloquent model? If you have can you check that you have included `use App\User;` at the top of your class that you are calling it from.

Comment: You can also use `\Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser::find(4)` directly too if you need but its usually handier to have your own User model.

Comment: I'm using the code in my view, and in the controller use App\User; script has been used , and User model extends extends EloquentUser, is also present.